# Spring find bean's without annotations

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Can spring find implementation of interfaces without `@Component`(and other) annotations on class, and without explicit bean declaration in xml? Just scan packages and find class that implement interface?

Comment: Yes, have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)?

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe some keyword?

Comment: Keyword for what? The link is to the exact section that describes how to modify/configure component-scanning. Cannot be more clear then that.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah, i just start reading before page loaded, so i not seen the is an anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)

> By default, classes annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service,
>   @Controller, or a custom annotation that itself is annotated with
>   @Component are the only detected candidate components. However, you
>   can modify and extend this behavior simply by applying custom filters.
>   Add them as include-filter or exclude-filter sub-elements of the
>   component-scan element. Each filter element requires the type and
>   expression attributes. The following table describes the filtering
>   options.

**Table 3.5. Filter Types**

> assignable **|** org.example.SomeClass    **|** A class (or interface)
>   that the target components are assignable to (extend/implement).